# Symfony: ServiceNotFoundException after update

Tags: symfony

After updating my Symofny projet from 3.2.* to 3.3.* I faced this exception:

```
ServiceNotFoundException
The service "fos_user.profiler.controller" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_user.email_update_confirmation".
```

So you guys know these  steps:

1- In order to optimize the performance I have launched this command:

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize --no-dev --classmap-authoritative
```

2- I did the upgrade from 3.2.* to 3.3.*
3- Did the same command as in the first step

After this I faced this exception !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known problem. One of the PR on GH solves it. Now to fix it add

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        confirmation:
              enabled: true
```

in config. Of course if you have existing `fos_user` in config just add that what is missing.

Comment: Thanks this worked by putting it `true` but this was working fine without this configuration before ?!!

Comment: I don't know when but they broke something. In 2.0.2 everything was working fine. As I mentioned, in future version the PR with the fix will be merged.